# Electron fails to find react module on its installed dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, asar

My app works fine in `npm run dev` &/or `yarn run build` && `yarn start`

But packaged version fails to find dependencies *of* dependencies, specifically 'react' within react-player or react-countup.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react' Require stack:

/Applications/ElectronReact.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-countup/build/index.js

/Applications/ElectronReact.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/app.html at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:717) at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (reset-search-paths.ts:40) at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:622) at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717) at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68) at Object. (/Applications/ElectronReact.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-countup/build/index.js:8) at Object. (/Applications/ElectronReact.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-countup/build/index.js:600) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880)

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720
```

It's a React, Firebase, Redux, REST API app.

I checked it packaged and opened properly first before doing much with the boilerplate. Just stripped back some counter logic and put in some basic styling etc.

I have installed (firebase, react-player, react-countup) dependencies at `app/package.json` level not `root/pkg json`

Unsure how/why app's ability to find React would've changed by anything i've done. I dont think i've touched any config for a while. And even then it was the `main.dev.js` not `main.prod.js` - which looks like it's gone through a transpiler and i wouldn't know how to edit anyway.

[image: electron app web dependency error]

The nuts and bolts of this:
Error suggests it's failing to find 'react' via the common JS loader, loading modular js into browser. That's when it's loading the react-countup package. If i remove that npm pkg and then re-package my app, it fails with same error on the next dependency i installed (react-player). If i kill that, it moves onto `Prismic-ReactJS` pkg.

Have i installed packages at the wrong level? (app/package.json)
Do i need to link dependencies OF dependencies somehow?
Is there a main.js setting somewhere that I've tweaked by accident?

Can anyone help?